# MSM & channel entries

Tags: channel-entries, multi-site-manager, channel

First time user of MSM here. I'm building 3 sites that all have the same channels. In some cases, I want only the default site to make channel entries, but want all 3 sites to have access to those entries. In other cases, I want the individual sites to insert their own channel entries and only display those entries in their respective sites.

Can I do the above in MSM?

(I thought MSM allowed me to share everything across sites. I found out during setup that I can make copies of channels, templates, etc. This means each site is working on its copy of the default site, not sharing resources. It's cause a bit of a problems for me. For templates, I will be sharing across sites via symlinks. Now, I'm trying to figure out how to deal with channel entries.)

Comment: where do you want to share it it? for frontend? Use site="siteA|siteB|siteC" parameter in this case. Read http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/sites/code.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can pull content across sites. That the site setup process allows you to copy an existing site doesn't change that.

You can embed templates across sites using an embed statement:

```
{embed="default_site:embeds/html_header"}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by sharing templates via a symlink.